# Why was this question deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I just saw this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3678/what-was-the-t-1001s-posing-as-catherine-weaver-mission), which has been mod deleted. [Another Question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142777/why-does-catherine-weaver-want-to-stop-skynet?noredirect=1&lq=1) was marked as duplicate of the one that has been deleted.

Preview for members who can't view deleted posts:

[image]

The question:

1. is Highly upvoted (15 as of now)
2. is About a Sci-fi franchise
3. is Not offensive or against the policies AFAIK
4. has an answer with 12 upvotes

I am not asking for it to be undeleted since I don't even know why was it deleted. I just want to learn the reason behind the deletion.

If it remains deleted, what happens to the question that is closed as duplicate of that deleted question? Do we reopen it then?

Comment: Yes, there was a vote to reopen on the question that was marked as a duplicate of this now deleted question. That is what brought me here.

Comment: @Skooba Yup there are currently two reopen votes on that. I haven't voted yet and won't do until we learn what's going to happen to the deleted question

Comment: @Aegon - It should be reopened, at least until this deleted question is open again. I'm really at a loss why it's been closed.

Comment: @Valorum I cast the final vote to reopen then. As to why it was closed, I would assume you would know since you were among the people who closed it? Can't say anything about it as I don't know much about the terminator franchise

Comment: @Aegon - Arguably the original question had the worse (less detailed) answer so I can see a case for closing it as a dupe of the newer question. I can also see an argument for merging them since the questions were so very close. What I can't see is any argument for deleting the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3678/what-was-the-t-1001s-posing-as-catherine-weaver-mission) shouldn't have been deleted and it certainly shouldn't have been *deleted by moderator action* without the moderator offering an explanation in comments.

Per the "[theory of moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)"

> **Whenever possible, try to leave frequent comments on posts where
>   you've taken (or considered taking) a moderator action, explaining the
>   reasoning. This is important so that community members can learn the
>   norms of the community and the moderation policies.**

The power to mod-delete a question is one of the most powerful actions a moderator can take. Any action which involves a deletion should require some explication.  The deletion of an elderly (and highly upvoted) question with an elderly (and highly upvoted) answer, doubly so.

---

**Moving forward**

- [The question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3678/what-was-the-t-1001s-posing-as-catherine-weaver-mission) <s>should be</s> has been undeleted by a moderator. Evidently it was deleted in error.
- The [other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142777/why-does-catherine-weaver-want-to-stop-skynet?noredirect=1&lq=1) should be reclosed as a dupe and considered for merger since both have good answers.

Comment: The question was closed by mistake and was reopened.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze - I assumed it was something like that. It seemed very out of character for you. Given that both questions have upvoted answers, perhaps a merger might be more appropriate?

Comment: I agree. I think the correct question got closed (I can't say that the newer question is any better that the older one), but the *answer* on the now-closed question is better than the one on the still-open one... a merge would make sense.